# How much is it acceptable to partially answer a post within an edit of that post?

Tags: discussion, editing

I have encountered a situation in which the OP asked a relatively simple question about manipulating logarithms.  The OP was clearly not practiced in the subject, and asked a question involving the simplification of $\log{x}/\log{10}$.  I answered the question soon after it was asked.  Someone then edited the post for clarity, but in doing so, changed the posting to $\log_{10}{x}$.

I asked the editor of the post if it was OK to partially answer the question in the edit.  To be honest, I don't feel very good about it, because it takes away some of the content of the OP's question and robs other readers of finding out what the OP needed to know.  That said, I would like to ask the community if there is a policy  on edits in that direction.

Comment: I feel this sort of edit should be rolled back, since it changes the content of the question. E.g., the question "why $\sin^2 x +\cos^2 x=1$ ?" is not the same as "why $1=1$?".

Comment: OK, good, I'm not the only one who feels this way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since no other answers were posted, I'll repeat my comment here. This sort of edit should be rolled back, since it changes the mathematical content of the question, not merely its presentation.

Comment: I agree, I have changed back the troublesome part.

Answer (score 2):

I expect this question to be edited to reflect the knowledge acquired, rendering this answer mute, in a circular manner answering hereby your question.

Comment: What?$\vphantom{}$

Comment: [Godel, Escher, Bach?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel,_Escher,_Bach)

Comment: The question of whether this answer is mute, is moot.